# Is there any difference between {strlen($var) == 0} and {empty($var)}

Tags: php, post, forms

considering that the variable only can be String fetched from an HTML Form (input-text, textarea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between `strlen($str)==0` and `empty($str)`. [`empty`](http://docs.php.net/empty) returns *true* if the value is `"0"`. See the [PHP type comparison tables](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = 0;

strlen( $var ); // 1, coerced to true

empty($var) // true, it's considered "empty", these are the empty ones:
```

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some note I've discovered:
**empty()**, requires a **variable and only a variable**, so I think it has a problem when it's dealing with an object value fetched from the magic **__get()** method.

Comment: support for expressions [added in PHP 5.5](http://www.php.net/migration55.new-features#migration55.new-features.empty) :-)