# PHP best way to check whether a string is empty or not

Tags: php

I've seen a lot of php code that does the following to check whether a string is valid by doing:

$str is a string variable.

```
if (!isset($str) || $str !== '') {
  // do something
}
```

I prefer to just do

```
if (strlen($str) > 0) {
  // something
}
```

Is there any thing that can go wrong with the second method?  Are there any casting issues I should be aware of?

Comment: Um.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php?

Comment: Good points.  I should be aware of strings with trailing whitespaces

Comment: yup, there is. An error would be thrown if $str is undefined.

Comment: You're also presuming in the 2nd method that `$str` is previously defined - if not, you'll get an 'undefined variable' notice. The use of `isset()` in the first method checks this.

Comment: @richsage no, not isset(), but empty().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718986/checking-if-the-string-is-empty

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel true, `empty()` will do both. Was highlighting the undefined issue :-)

Comment: Yada, please feel free to change your accepted answer. I'm happy to delete mine since it originally was misleading/misinformed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since PHP will treat a string containing a zero ('0') as empty, it makes the `empty()` function an ***unsuitable*** solution.

Instead, test that the variable is ***explicitly*** not equal to an empty string:

`$stringvar !== ''`

As the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45066/yada) and [Gras Double](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289317/gras-double) and others have shown, the variable should also be checked for initialization to avoid a warning or error (depending on settings):

`isset($stringvar)`

This results in the more acceptable:

```
if (isset($stringvar) && $stringvar !== '') {
}
```

*PHP has a lot of bad conventions. I originally answered this (over 9 years ago) using the `empty()` function, as seen below. I've long since abandoned PHP, but since this answer attracts downvotes and comments every few years, I've updated it. Should the OP wish to change the accepted answer, please do so.*

**Original Answer:**

> ```
> if(empty($stringvar))
> {
>     // do something
> }
> ```
>
> You could also add `trim()` to eliminate whitespace if that is to be considered.
>
> **Edit:**
>
> Note that for a string like '`0`', this will return true, while `strlen()` will not.

Comment: is there any different between if(empty(trim($str)))  and if (strlen(trim($strim))> 0) ?

Comment: Yes. Consider the string `'0'` on which `empty()` will return true while `strlen()` will not.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318350/is-there-any-difference-between-strlenvar-0-and-emptyvar

Comment: This is worse than `strlen( $str ) > 0` because it considers `"0"` to be an empty string.

Comment: "Worse" depends on the OP's requirement. If "0" should be treated as *not* empty, then this method is not ideal. It is just an alternate suggestion. However, in many situations, "0" might just as well be empty. It's situational.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this method because a string value of `"0"` is considered empty.

Comment: As explained by Jesse, this answer is WRONG!

Comment: This will fail if you validate the string '0'. A string with the zero digit will be assumed empty.

Comment: @JeanPaulRuiz Yes. It's been mentioned (repeatedly) in previous comments as well as an addendum in the answer.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've edited this (again) to hopefully avoid having any newcomers stumble upon the horrific mistakes made 9+ years ago.

Answer (score 16):

You need `isset()` in case `$str` is possibly undefined:

```
if (isset($str) && $str !== '') {
    // variable set, not empty string
}
```

Using `!empty()` would have an important caveat: the string `'0'` [evaluates to false](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Also, sometimes one wants to check, in addition, that `$str` is not something falsy, like `false` or `null`[1]. The previous code doesn't handle this. It's one of the rare situations where loose comparison may be useful:

```
if (isset($str) && $str != '') {
    // variable set, not empty string, not falsy
}
```

The above method is interesting as it remains concise and doesn't filter out `'0'`. But make sure to document your code if you use it.

Otherwise you can use this equivalent but more verbose version:

```
if (isset($str) && (string) $str !== '') {
    // variable set, not empty string, not falsy
}
```

Of course, if you are sure `$str` is defined, you can omit the `isset($str)` from the above codes.

Finally, considering that `'' == false`, `'0' == false`, but `'' != '0'`, you may have guessed it: [PHP comparisons aren't transitive](http://www.phpsadness.com/sad/52) (fun graphs included).

[1] Note that `isset()` already filters out `null`.

Answer (score 10):

This will safely check for a string containing only whitespace:

```
// Determines if the supplied string is an empty string.                                                                                 
// Empty is defined as null or containing only whitespace.                                                                               
// '0' is NOT an empty string!                                                                                                           
function isEmptyString($str) {
  return !(isset($str) && (strlen(trim($str)) > 0));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
if( !isset($str[0]) )
   echo "str is NULL or an empty string";
```

I found it on PHP manual in a comment by [Antone Roundy](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#77845)

I posted it here, because I did some tests and it seems to work well, but I'm wondering if there is some side effect I'm not considering. Any suggestions in comments here would be appreciated.

Comment: Note this method also supports `'0'`, `false`, `null` (gives respectively true, false, false) as in the loose comparison `== ''` stuff in my answer.

Comment: @GrasDouble: yep, you are right. The problem would be ehn string is '0'

Comment: There was a misunderstanding. I meant your code considers `'0'` to be a non-empty string, just like any other string. So it's working fine actually :)

Answer (score 2):

According to PHP empty() doc (https://www.php.net/empty):

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). 
> **Instead, use trim($name) == false**.

Comment: No wonder my empty code is always return error in PHP 5.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This simple old question is still tricky.

`strlen($var)` works perfectly ONLY if you're absolutely sure the $var is a string.

`isset($var)` and `empty($var)` result are based on type of the variable, and could be tricky at some cases (like empty string ""). View the table in this [page](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/) for more details.

**UPDATE**

There are actually 2 cases for this question:

**Case 1: You're sure that your variable is *always* going to be a "string":**

In this case, just test the length:

```
if(strlen($str) > 0) {
    // do something..
}
```

**Case 2: Your variable *may and may not* be a "string":**

In this case, it depends on what you want to do. For me (most of the time), if it's not a string then I validate it as "false". You can do it this way:

```
if(is_string($var) && $var !== '') {// true only if it's a string AND is not empty
    // do something ...
}
```

And to make it shorter and in 1 condition instead of 2 (specially useful if you're testing more than 1 string in same if condition), I made it into function:

```
function isNonEmptyString($var) {
    return is_string($var) && $var !== '';
}


// Somewhere else..
// Reducing conditions to half
if(isNonEmptyString($var1) && isNonEmptyString($var2) && isNonEmptyString($var3)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your variable `$str` is not defined then your `strlen()` method will throw an exception. That is the whole purpose of using `isset()` first.

Answer (score 0):

trimming the string will also help if there are string with white spaces.

```php
if (isset($str) &&  trim($str) !== '') {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think not, because strlen (string lenght) returns the lenght (integer) of your $str variable.
So if the variable is empty i would return 0. Is 0 greater then 0. Don't think so.
But i think the first method might be a little more safer. Because it checks if the variable is init, and if its not empty.